# Require RegEx Engine to fail

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches the following format.

```
hhhh:mm or hhhhmm
```

hhhh are hours (first digit should match 1-9 followed by numbers, not more than 4 digits)

mm are minutes (first digit should match 0-5 followed by a number, not more than 2 digits)

The following format should also be possible - mm or m

So far I have

```
^([1-9]\d{0,3}:?)?([0-5]\d{0,2})?\d
```

which matches what i want but doesn't fail if I enter e.g. 4444444.

In fact if I have less than 3 digits they should be treated a minutes in the range 0..59.

Any help is appreciated.
I'm not a regex guru at all.

Comment: Why should it fail with `444444`?

Comment: Sorry, bad example. I missed another digit. (Post edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
^(?:([1-9]\d{0,3}):?)?([0-5]?\d)$
```

That would allow a single digit minute even if hours part is present. If you don't want that it could be solved in some different ways, eg:

```
^(?:([1-9]\d{0,3}):?)?([0-5]\d)$|^(\d)$
```

Comment: Not quite. This will match e.g. 89 as well, which is wrong as 2 digits mean minutes.